# Browser says "Waiting for www.xyz.com" for a very long time

Tags: wordpress, host

When I load my website (hosted with Ipage). The browser often takes an incredible long time saying "Waiting for www.xyz.com ..." before any elements of the site actually appear. After this "Waiting for" process, the text, images and everything else actually load quite fast.

I contacted my host with my tracert result and they said they optimized my website database and increased the memory available to PHP on my account to 64 Mb.They also said they have checked the issue by accessing my website and found that it is loading fine without any slowness. It seems to be a temporary issue. Please try to access your website with different browser and network.

I tried different browsers and networks but this "Waiting for" process always takes too long.

My website is http://www.surreyextra.com/ . It's Wordpress and BuddyPress. I'm in the UK while Ipage host is placed in the USA, can this potentially be a problem?

I have tried a number of optimizations, like minifying my CSS and JS files and use catching but the problem hasn't improved.

So is it my host's fault, should I contact them again?

Comment: I live in INDIA and I checked this link http://www.surreyextra.com/ in my firefox 11.0 . Its opening within 3-4 second. how much time its taking on your browser. once clear the cache of browser and then reply.

Comment: I'm in the UK, and using Chrome took about 8 secs for the page to appear the _first time_. However, subsequent requests (even after clearing the cache) took about 4 seconds. Inspecting the network using  development tools shows a significant delay before the initial response from the server - so the delay would certainly seem to be server-side. Try serving a static HTML page - with minimal server-side processing this should show how quick your server can be.

Comment: +1 For actually giving us a link.

Answer (score 0):

I had a peek at your site using Chrome and FireFox dev tools (network panel).

There's two places I suspect the bottle neck and I've outlined them below.

I noticed you are doing on-the-fly minifying (it looks like it's a plug-in). I would seriously consider thinking about having permanent minified versions rather than getting the server to do this every time. It definitely looks like you take a hit on the first load whilst the on--the-fly minifier compiles and sets up consolidated script for caching. I hope you're not minify scripts that are already minified...

I don't know anything about BuddyPress, but I suspect you're on a shared host account so another culprit for bottle neck is probably disk I/O. One way to test is to set up the same wordpress blog (with all the addons, scripts and themes) on wordpress.com and compare loading times. MySQL is running on the same host? This could also bring in latency if they have a heavily burdened MySQL server.

The page loaded fine for me, I'm wondering if the problem is with your or your client's net connection? Try switching your DNS to OpenDNS to see if it improves it.

Comment: "The page loaded fine for me" - How long do the pages take to load for you?

Comment: Went back to gather some stats, but the site appears to be broken getting 500 errors. :(